# Can a main() method of class be invoked from another class in java

Tags: java

Can a `main()` method of class be invoked in another class in java?

e.g.

```
class class1{

  public static void main(String []args){

  }

}

class class2{

  public static void main(String []args){
      class1.main();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 45):

If you want to call the main method of another class you can do it this way assuming I understand the question.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main() method of MyClass");
        OtherClass obj = new OtherClass();
    }
}

class OtherClass {

    public OtherClass() {

        // Call the main() method of MyClass
        String[] arguments = new String[] {"123"};
        MyClass.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: for those who may or may not notice... this will create an infinite loop

Comment: @mmcrae This is recursion, not loop. Recursion is never infinite.

Comment: wait what...why would recursion not be infinite? You could blow your stack, but that is just a practical limitation, mathematical recursion can of course be infinite if you never make progress towards a base case (or no base case exists).

Comment: @JPC This is not mathematical recursion. It is computer programming. All resources are finite.

Answer (score 26):

if I got your question correct...

main() method is defined in the class below...

```
public class ToBeCalledClass{

   public static void main (String args[ ]) {
      System.out.println("I am being called");
   }
}
```

you want to call this main method in another class.

```
public class CallClass{

    public void call(){
       ToBeCalledClass.main(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: great.i was wondering what to put as `main` argument ! simply it was `null`

Answer (score 2):

yes, but only if main is declared public

Comment: ... or protected, or package private, or you do tricky things with reflection to allow it to be invoked despite being private.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the question is NOT about recursion. We can easily call `main` method of another class in your class. Following example illustrates static and calling by object. Note omission of word `static` in `Class2`

```
class Class1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("this is class 1");
    }    
}

class Class2{
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("this is class 2");
    }    
}

class MyInvokerClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("this is MyInvokerClass");
        Class2 myClass2 = new Class2();
        Class1.main(args);
        myClass2.main(args);
    }    
}
```

Output Should be:

> this is wrapper class
>
> this is class 1
>
> this is class 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as it is public and you pass the correct args.
See this link for more information.
http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-CommandLine.shtml#mainhost

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
// Java method to show Calling main() method
// externally from the same class

import java.io.*;

class GFG {

    static int count = 0;

    // The method that calls the main() method
    static void mainCaller()
    {

        System.out.println("mainCaller!");
        count++;

        // Calling the main() only 3 times
        if (count < 3) {

            // Calling the main() method
            main(null);
        }
    }

    // main() method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("main");

        // Calling the mainCalller() method
        // so that main() methiod is called externally
        mainCaller();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Sure. Here's a completely silly program that demonstrates calling `main` recursively.

```
public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
        {
            if (args[i] != "")
            {
                args[i] = "";
                System.out.println((args.length - i) + " left");
                main(args);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: At least don't compare `String`s with `==` (or `!=`).