# Java chat room program

Tags: java, static, set, hashset

I have to display the current user into the gui, but it keep saying the the hashset is empty, this has been bugging me for hours. What is the easiest way to fix this? There might be a lot of un used code as i was testing things trying to make it work.

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    Server.names();
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server {    
    public static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{                    
        while(true){
            name = in.readLine();
            if(name == null){
                return;
            }
            if(!names.contains(name)){
                 names.add(name);
                 break;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to narrow down the amount of code you post here. If the problem is with your HashSet being empty you should show us the portion of code that populates and uses the set.

Comment: i tried to simplify as much as i could, thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no point in checking if a set contains an item before adding it, just add it. Checking if the element is in the set is just as expensive. And since it's a set it's guaranteed to be the same element if it's a duplicate.

Comment: i need to read it in the client class because i have to pass the data into a gui. In other words how can i read the hashset from a different class without creating a new object

Answer (score 1):

Your Q is a bit unclear, but if you want to get the `HashSet`, `names` from your `Server` class, you need to get the reference to it by calling `Server.name`, not `Server.name()` as it is not a method.

Now `names` will be empty until you populate it. To populate it you need to call code that will read user input and store it in `names`. In this case you can call the `main` method of `Server` (see this related Q [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550310/can-a-main-method-of-class-be-invoked-in-another-class-in-java)) but unless you really want that to be your `main` method of `Server`, I would recommend renaming the method to `populateNames()` or something similar.

Comment: When i use that, the client class reads public static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>() which is empty, and its not reading the names that i added

Comment: @user3238481 please see updated explanation. BTW presumably in your `Server` class, `in` is a `static Scanner` you have declared and initialised?