# How can I call this specific method from one class in another?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a main method in one public class called "Dated" that looks like this

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException
```

Now I want to call this main method in another class called "Puzzle2" and in another method static void edit;

How can I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a main() method of class be invoked in another class in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550310/can-a-main-method-of-class-be-invoked-in-another-class-in-java)

Comment: This one throws an Exception...

Answer (score 0):

Strictly avoid Calling main ; its not best practice to code like that .

And btw the main is a static method you can't create object and call it

instead change your main into a function dated() and use different class file for main .

So that u can call the dated () function with instances of classes whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is not practice though, I'm using a date function in an arraylist database for a university project