# Can we create an object of the class in which main function is defined in Java?

Tags: java, object, methods, program-entry-point

Is it possible to create object of class in which main method resides.I have been searching for this answer but I have been told that it depends on compiler some compiler will allow while others will not.Is that true?

Comment: Nope, just call `new MainClass()` or whatever the main class name is.  Some example code will help.

Comment: No, it's not true that it depends on compiler.  Did you try creating an object of that class?  What happened when you did?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550310/can-a-main-method-of-class-be-invoked-from-another-class-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. The main method is just an entry point. The class is like any other, except it has an additional `public static` method. The main method is static and therefore not part of the instance of the object, but you shouldn't be using the main method anyway except for starting the program.

```
public class Scratchpad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratchpad scratchpad = new Scratchpad();
        scratchpad.someMethod();
    }

    public Scratchpad() {
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Non-static method prints");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create object for the class which has main method. There is no difference in this class and a class which don't have main method with respect to creating objects and using.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is not limited to one class, you can place it within any class.

As for different JVM implementations having different standards, that I am unsure of.
It doesn't sound correct, being unable to instantiate the class within itself would create constraints.

```java
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
    }
}
```